# Why is this MAX86161 internal LDO wired this way?

Tags: ldo

I'm looking at the MAXM86161EVSYS and am not sure why the pulse-ox senseor LDO_EN and LDO output is wired this way

I see the purpose of R1A and R1B, to allow the ability to pull the enable high or low.

But what's with R5? When would I ever want to tie an LDO output to it's own enable?

[Eval System Datatsheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAXM86161EVSYS.pdf)

[MAX86161 Datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAXM86161.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Normally LDO_EN is driven through R8 (0) by the ARM core microcontroller MAX32664 (U2), and R1A R1B R5 are left open (DNI = Do Not Install). Most likely it's really a stealthy test point used during prototype development, and may have been used for some purpose during IC road test. I don't see any description in the text so it probably doesn't need to be there. Bootstrapping an LDO from its own output doesn't seem likely.

Comment: @MarkU I see. So no functional purpose most likely. When we got this R5 was actually populated but I suspect that's probably unintentional.